# Finding the rating score of a URL

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, nlp

I am trying to create a dataframe consisting reviews on 20 banks and in the following code I am trying to get the 20 customers rating score value but finding it difficult as I am new BeautifulSoup and Webscraping.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.bankbazaar.com/reviews.html'
page = requests.get(url)
print(page.text)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html.parser')


 Rating = []
rat_elem = soup.find_all('span')
for rate in rat_elem:
    Rating.append(rate.find_all('div').get('value')) 

 print(Rating)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.bankbazaar.com/reviews.html'
page = requests.get(url)
print(page.text)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html.parser')

# Find all the span elements where the "itemprop" attribute is "ratingvalue". 
Rating = [item.text for item in soup.find_all('span', attrs={"itemprop":"ratingvalue"})]


print(Rating)
# The output
# ['4.0', '5.0', '5.0', '5.0', '4.0', '4.0', '5.0', '5.0', '5.0', '5.0', '4.0', '5.0', '5.0', '5.0', '5.0', '4.0', '4.5', '4.0', '4.0', '4.0']
```

[BeautifulSoup keyword arguments](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#kwargs)

Comment: can you tell me why you haven chosen 'itemprop:rating value'

Comment: "ratingvalue" is the rating the user gave, while "bestrating" is the maximum the user can give. "ratingvalue" seem to be the more suitable choice imo. (Not sure if that's what you're asking.)

Comment: Well I was browsing the html code and could not find it.

Comment: I used the "developer tools" in Chrome to navigate the elements. That's Ctrl-Shift-I, or just right click the item in the page then click "inspect". It will bring you to the element within the webpage source code... In Firefox right click "inspect element" the shortcut remains the same (as chrome).

Comment: In Firefox right click "inspect element" the shortcut remains the same (as chrome), it's called "inspector" instead of "developer tools".

Answer (score 2):

I prefer using CSS selectors, so you should be able to target all the spans by targeting the ones with the `itemprop` attribute set to `ratingvalue`.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.bankbazaar.com/reviews.html'
page = requests.get(url)
print(page.text)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html.parser')

Rating = []
for rate in soup.select('span[itemprop=ratingvalue]'):
    Rating.append(rate.get_text()) 

print(Rating)
```

Relevant output

```
['4.0', '5.0', '5.0', '5.0', '4.0', '4.0', '5.0', '5.0', '5.0', '5.0', '4.0', '5.0', '5.0', '5.0', '5.0', '4.0', '4.5', '4.0', '4.0', '4.0']
```

EDIT: add relevant output

Comment: Agreed. Not sure why find seems to be so popular.

Comment: I think it is because for so long `select` was so limited. If you are new to bs4, you'll find hundreds of more `find`/`find_all` examples.

Comment: Ah... I guess I am new to python but not so new to CSS so am benefiting from recent changes. Find seems like a more expensive/slower method to me I thought.

Comment: Yeah, seems to me if you are scraping a lot of HTML, you know HTML and CSS. And if you know CSS, why would you want to use the more awkward `find` unless you are taking advantage of features you can't get with select, like regex etc. But old habits die hard if you've used bs4 when find was the best option.